# How to view all stashes at once?

Tags: git, git-stash

It's time-consuming to read through dozens of stashes, one-by-one, by issuing:

```sh
git stash show -p 'stash@{N}' # Where "N" is the stash index
```

Is there a way to view all stashes at once (in patch form)? Note that I don't want to view all the stashes merged into one big patch because that would prevent me from applying a specific stash, which is what I want to do.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Is it possible you are looking for the command

```
git stash list -p
```

As mentioned in http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash 
you can add all options from git log to git stash list...

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you